# can anyone explain 聞きたいっておっしゃてました

Tags: grammar

Im scratching my head trying to figure out grammar behind マリアさんの話を聞きたいっておっしゃってましたよ。

Its from my text book, which is translated into something like want to hear his word saying about it. I knew 聞きたい = want to hear, おっしゃる = polite word for say/speak, but couldnt put them together.

I guess there are some sort of contracted speech involved since the conversation is somewhat casual, but there isnt sufficient grammar guide for it in my book, nor could I google anything helpful beyond auto translation. Can anyone explain it to me and guide me roughly through this "contracted form" puzzle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a conversational form of

```
聞きたいとおっしゃていました
```

where って is a conversational form of the quoting と reporting something being said, and the い of いました is elided as it usually is in conversational speech.

Comment: thank!

Is there any rule book I can learn this from? Its quite hard for an elementary learner to wade through these non text book expressions while hes still relying on dictionary for more than half of any given sentence.